# NSCounted set ignoring a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscountedset

I'm trying to do a `NSCountedSet` but I need to ignore a property, I tried overriding the `isEqual` method of my object, and doing a manual compare of all the properties except the one I want to ignore but it doesn't work

Any idea on how to achieve it?

**UPDATE**

My class

```
@interface GSOrderMenuMenuContent : GSBaseModel

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber        *order_content_id;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber        *item_id;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber        *price;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber        *priceWithModifiers;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString        *course;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString        *itemName;

@property (nonatomic) GSMenuItem*           item;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray        *modifiers;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSNumber        *isAlreadyPrinted;

@property (copy,nonatomic)  NSNumber        *isDeleted;

-(GSOrderMenuMenuContent*)deepCopy;

-(GSOrderContent*)  orderContent;

-(BOOL)isEqual:(GSOrderMenuMenuContent*)object;
@end
```

Usage:

```
    NSCountedSet* countedSet    = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:contents];
```

Where contents is an array of class objects

Adding a breakpoint to the `isEqual` gets not called (however it is if doing a `[NSarray containsObject:...]`

Comment: Show the class you have and some example usage of the `NSCountedSet`.

Comment: OK, so.  What is the property you are trying to ignore?  What is your implementation of `isEqual`?  Why are you using `NSNumber` objects rather than primitive types?

Comment: Update your question with the implementation of both the `isEqual:` method and the `hash` method (you did properly implement `hash` too, right?).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the hash method, I'm gonna check it

Comment: Why are the `NSNumber` properties defined as `copy`? There's no point since there is no mutable `NSNumber` class you might assign to one of them.

Comment: @Maddy, it was the hash method, overriding it worked!

Comment: @rmaddy How is there no point? It very much makes sense to do so. There can very well be mutable number objects at some point. If the type is immutable, `copy` does the same as `retain`, it's not like you would waste time by actually copying the object unless it is mutable.

Comment: And just another thing, what if I want to use the standard sometimes, and my own in other occasions?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr How can you have a mutable `NSNumber`? There's no `NSMutableNumber` class.

Comment: @rmaddy I was saying that at some point there may be. And you could even make your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs for the `isEqual:` method, you must always implement a corresponding `hash` method. Those two methods must always be implemented together.

Two objects that compare as equal must also return the same `hash` value.

Comment: Why answer the question when it's clearly a dupe?

Comment: If it's clearly a dupe, where's your vote to close as a dupe? :) Admittedly, on occasion I forget to search first.